# StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I've read about the [StaleElementReferenceException](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp) in the official documentation, but I still don't understand why my code is raising this exception? Does `browser.get()` instantiate a new spider?

```
class IndiegogoSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'indiegogo'
    allowed_domains = [ 'indiegogo.com' ]
    start_urls = [ 'https://www.indiegogo.com/explore/all?project_type=all&project_timing=all&sort=trending' ]

    def parse(self, response):

        if (response.status != 404):
            options = Options()
            options.add_argument('-headless')
            browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)
            browser.get(self.start_urls[0])

            show_more = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="text-center"]/a'))
            )

            while True:
                try:
                    show_more.click()
                except Exception:
                    break

            hrefs = WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(
                EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="discoverableCard"]/a'))
            )

            for href in hrefs:
                browser.get(href.get_attribute('href'))

                #
                # will be scraping individual pages here
                #


            browser.close()
```

I've tried the following to no avail. I've also tried placing the `links` variable elsewhere in the script, in a different scope, also to no avail.

```
            links = []

            for href in hrefs:
                links.append(href.get_attribute('href'))

            for link in links:
                browser.get(href.get_attribute('href'))

                #
                # will be scraping individual pages here
                #
```

Not sure why `hrefs` and especially `links` are erased from memory? When I extract the value of the `href` attribute of each item in the `hrefs` iterable, and then stick all of the URLs in the `links` variable, shouldn't the `links` list be independent of the DOM and page changes?

Not sure what to do at this point. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Anthony, your second code block with `links` should work, it just looks like you have a copy/paste bug:

```
for link in links:
    browser.get(href.get_attribute('href'))
```

should be

```
for link in links:
    browser.get(link)
    ...
```

Comment: it's funny. i was just messing around in my editor and saw it and then saw the notification for this answer! lol. just testing it now

Answer (score 2):

As documentaion says:

A stale element reference exception is thrown in one of two cases, the first being more common than the second:

- The element has been deleted entirely.
- The element is no longer attached to the DOM.

In your case it is:

- The element is no longer attached to the DOM.

It is because of `browser.get(href.get_attribute('href'))`. When you are redirecting to the another page, your DOM will be completely reloaded and the `hrefs` does not reference to the elements from previous page. That's why you are getting an error.

How to deal with this error? You can do like this:

```
links = []

    for href in hrefs: # store all links as a strings
        links.append(href.get_attribute('href'))

    for link in links: # then just use them
        browser.get(link)
```

Comment: yeah, that's what i was going for initially. unfortunately, as @tankthinks also pointed out, i forgot to change `browser.get(href.get_attribute('href'))` to `browser.get(link)` in my `link in links` loop :(